# window c++ : how to timeout receiveFrom function in a udp based conversation

Tags: c++, windows, timeout, udp

I am trying to create a reliable service on top of UDP.
Here i need to timeout `receiveFrom` function of window c++ if not packet arrives 
in specified time.
In java i do this `DatagramSocket.setSoTimeout` but i dont know how to achieve this in windows c++.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [`setsockopt()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740476(VS.85).aspx) specifically `SO_RCVTIMEO`.

Answer (score 3):

Try using [select](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Waiting-for-I_002fO.html).  This will work on both TCP and UDP sockets.  Just another way to do the same thing as in Len's answer, but instead of setting a timeout for all recv operations on the socket you can set the length of the timeout on a call by call basis.

```
 #include <errno.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <sys/time.h>

 int
 input_timeout (int filedes, unsigned int seconds)
 {
   fd_set set;
   struct timeval timeout;

   /* Initialize the file descriptor set. */
   FD_ZERO (&set);
   FD_SET (filedes, &set);

   /* Initialize the timeout data structure. */
   timeout.tv_sec = seconds;
   timeout.tv_usec = 0;

   /* select returns 0 if timeout, 1 if input available, -1 if error. */
   return TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY (select (FD_SETSIZE,
                                      &set, NULL, NULL,
                                      &timeout));
 }

 int
 main (void)
 {
   fprintf (stderr, "select returned %d.\n",
            input_timeout (STDIN_FILENO, 5));
   return 0;
 }
```